# Visulaization problem in uploading webpage with Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm trying to build up a webpage using Jekyll and GitHub as host. 
However the site looks different when pushed to with hub.

Here's how I see it on my local page

[image]

while on GitHub I get this

[image]

How could I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `baseurl` value in the config file when deploying to GitHub as a **project page**.

For example, if your GitHub repository is at `https://github.com/lorenzo/myblog`, then you need to have the following in the config file:

```
baseurl: "/myblog"
```

Otherwise if your repo is at `https://github.com/lorenzo/lorenzo.github.io`, then `baseurl` is optional. It can be set to `nil` or `""` in this case.